# Cycle maps as edge maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, hodge-theory, chern-classes

Given a smooth projective algebraic variety over $\mathcal{C}$, let $X$ be its associated complex analytic space.

The exponential sequence on $X$:

$$0\to\mathbf{Z}(1)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to 1$$
can be used to define the first Chern class, or equivalently the first cycle map from the group $\text{CH}^1(X) = \text{Pic}(X)$ of divisors on $X$ up to rational equivalence, as an **edge map** in a long cohomology exact sequence.

Is there a way to define all cycle maps

$$\text{CH}^n(X)\to H^{2n}(X,\mathbf{Z}(n))$$

as edge maps in a long exact sequence? Maybe some kind of exponential sequence involving K-theory sheaves?